# Pass javaScript variable to php or workaround for just php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to get a JavaScript variable to php without refreshing the page or submitting the form.  I think my problem is that php is on the server side.  I have a button that's set in a php echo...

`<input type='button' value='Edit' name='editbtn' onmouseup='reply_click(this.id)' onclick='edit()' id =  '" . $row['id'] . "'`

This button works correctly.  I didn't provide all the code surrounding it, just the part in question.  I can inspect the button element in the browser and the "id" shows the correct id number.

Next I'm using some test JavaScript in an effort to get the id to php with having to refresh the page or submit the form.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        function reply_click(clicked_id){
            var selid = clicked_id;
            alert(selid);
            document.writeln(selid);        
        } </script>";
```

This code works.  I get the correct id to show in an alert or document.writeln.  The problem comes when I try to set this to a php variable like this...

```
$testid = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.writeln(selid);</script>";
echo $testid;
```

$testid returns nothing.

Is there a way to do this or is there a workaround using only php?  I need to do this without submitting the form or refreshing the page.  Is that possible?  The end goal is to create another MySQL statement using that id value.  For example: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = the $testid from JavaScript.

Thank you!

Comment: Use AJAX to send to PHP without reloading.

Comment: I've been trying to get ajax working.  I have the type set to POST, data to the variable listed in the code above, set as `data: {name: selid}`, and the datatype is text.  When I try to echo the value using `echo $_POST['name']` I get an error stating, Undefined array key "name".  

If I check it with if !empty I can determine that nothing is actually posting.  How does the variable disappear going into ajax?

If I do get any data back from ajax, I get the html for the entire page.

Comment: If you're sending to the same URL as the page, it needs to execute different code depending on whether it's being loaded normally or responding to the AJAX request.

Comment: I am trying to send to the same URL as the page.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes it is possible but as @Barmar said you need to have a separate execution branch for it. The only real reason for "regular" and AJAX calls to point to a single script file is if there's a bunch of "setup" that's shared between the two. If not, you're better off separating them. If [as in comments to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020564/store-javascript-variable-in-a-php-variable-without-page-refresh) you store the value in a session variable, you can access the stored value both with AJAX calls and subsequent page loads, for a database query or otherwise.