# Store JavaScript variable in a php variable without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I've been been through numerous articles on here and tried dozens of variations including ajax.  What I want to do is click a button and store the id of that button in a php variable without having to refresh the page.

I've tried using isset and POST and I get some variation of Undefined key array.

Ajax was suggested but when I use ajax I can get the variable stored, but I'm unable to get it into a php variable.

Current setup...

I have an HTML button from which I need the id stored in a php variable so I can use it in another SQL statement.  This button is part of an HTML table of MySQL records returned from the db.

```
<input type='button' value='Edit' name='editbtn' onclick='edit(this.id)' id =  '" . $row['id'] . "'/>
```

JavaScript...

```
function edit(clicked_id){
        var selid = clicked_id;
        var seleid = selid.toString();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {name: seleid},
            datatype: 'text',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(name);
                alert("Success, data is: " + data);  // This correctly returns the id of the button clicked
            },
     });
}
```

The PHP at the top of the page is...

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
    ob_clean();
    $varid = $_POST['name'];
    echo $varid;
    exit; 
}
```

PHP is not receiving anything.  Is there a way to do this?  I guess it's a backend/frontend issue?

Note: I have been able to store a JavaScript variable in an HTML tag but I've been unable to use it as part of a SQL statement, even after trimming the tags off of it.

Please help and thank you!

Comment: "PHP is not receiving anything" — If that is the case, then how do you explain `alert("Success, data is: " + data);  // This correctly returns the id of the button clicked`? That is what the PHP is sending back (i.e. what you stored in the `$varid` PHP variable)

Comment: If you want to _store it_ ie. _have it persist for later use_, you need to use e.g. `$_SESSION` variables, or write it to a file, or add it to a database. Otherwise, the value you send in only lives for the duration of the script, here from receiving to ```echo ... exit; /* pooff it's gone */``` .

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  So, when I try to store the php without using the javascript it returns an undefined array key error which is why I used the javascript.  Is there a way to fix that?  I've tried a lot of workarounds because trying javascript and can't make anything work so far.  Suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Markus, I'll give that a shot.  I figured that's what was happening.

Comment: If you want to store it it without reloading the page, AJAX (or Fetch, same thing for current purposes) is pretty much what you have. There are no "workarounds", you use Javascript to make asynchronous calls from the browser. Send via AJAX and store as `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];` -- then you can use `$_SESSION['name']` variable in other script calls (whether AJAX or regular page loads) that share the session (after calling `session_start();`. P.S. Your AJAX receiver is better off not being a part of the page that's "regularly loaded", make it a separate script.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it's returning an Undefined array key "name" error at `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];`.

Comment: `function() edit(clicked_id)`- what is that supposed to be? Why `()` after the `function` keyword?

Comment: Oops, just a typo on here.  I removed it.

Comment: If you get an undefined key notice for `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name']`, it simply means that the request you're sending to that script doesn't have 'name' in its post data. (I'm guessing you made a direct call to the script. It should be present with the AJAX call.) Simply check `if(isset($_POST['name']))` before the assignment. If you're unclear what exactly is being received by the script, `var_dump($_POST)` to debug.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this in your php code :

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if(isset($data['name']) && !empty($data['name'])){
    ob_clean();
    $varid = $_POST['name'];
    echo $varid;
    exit; 
}
```